# Return substring from SOQL Data

Tags: apex, soql

I would like to generate a shortned version of one of my column (Content__C) from SOQL in my Apex Controller.

This is the code I have currently which does not work?

```
public list<News__c> lstItem;
public string excerpt;

public list<News__c> getNewsItems(){
    lstItem = new list<News__c>();
    lstItem = [SELECT Id, Name, Title__C, Content__c, Publish_Date__c, 
                   (Select Id, Name, LastModifiedDate 
                   From Attachments 
                   Order By LastModifiedDate DESC) 
               FROM News__c ORDER BY Publish_Date__c DESC, Name DESC LIMIT :QueryLimit OFFSET :OffsetSize];
    return lstItem;
}

public void getExcerpt() {  
    excerpt = lstItem.Content__C.substring(0,255) +'...'; 
}
```

Comment: what is the error you get ? first off your lstItem is a local variable to getNewsItems() method, and your code cannot save until you make it public variable to be shared between getExcerpt() and getNewsItems() and once you do it you are dealing with a list so you cannot do list.substring you have to be using list[index].substring what is the purpose of this class is it a controller for a VF page?

Comment: @rao The purpose of this controller is to get records from SF for my VF page. The error I am recieving is `Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST<News__c> at line 25 column 19`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you controller should be modified as :

```
public list<News__c> lstItem;
public string excerpt;
public list<News__c> lstItem {get;set;}
public map<id,string> newsmap{get;set;}


public list<News__c> getNewsItems(){
    lstItem = new list<News__c>();
    lstItem = [SELECT Id, Name, Title__C, Content__c, Publish_Date__c, 
                   (Select Id, Name, LastModifiedDate 
                   From Attachments 
                   Order By LastModifiedDate DESC) 
               FROM News__c ORDER BY Publish_Date__c DESC, Name DESC LIMIT :QueryLimit OFFSET :OffsetSize];
    return lstItem;
}

public void getExcerpt() {  
newsmap = new map<id,string>();
    for(news__c news_lstItem : lstItem){
        newsmap.put(news_lstItem.Id,news_lstItem.Content__C.substring(0,255) +'...'); 
    }
}
```

Page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!lstItem}" var ="item">
news item string value: <apex:outputtext value="{!newsmap[item]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: The page outputs the SOQL within a Datatable so using your page code does not work. I have tried to adding `<apex:outputtext value="{!newsmap[article]}"/>` as my dataTable is defined as follows `<apex:dataTable value="{!newsitems}" var="article"` but still returns nothing.

Comment: did you check if the lstItem size > 0, is your soql returning any data also check the contents in the map

Comment: The SOQL and NewsItems function is returning data. How can I check to see whether the map contains data?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Wrapper class for your news items and put them in it:

```
public List<NewsWrapper> getNewsItems()
{
  lstItem = new List<NewsWrapper>();
  for (News__c item: [SELECT Id, Name, Title__C, Content__c, Publish_Date__c, 
                   (Select Id, Name, LastModifiedDate 
                   From Attachments 
                   Order By LastModifiedDate DESC) 
               FROM News__c ORDER BY Publish_Date__c DESC, Name DESC LIMIT :QueryLimit OFFSET :OffsetSize])
  {
    lstItem.add(new NewsWrapper(item);
  }

  return lstItem;
}

public class NewsWrapper
{
  public News__c item{get; private set}

  public NewsWrapper(News__c item)
  {
    this.item = item;
  }

  public String getExcerpt()
  {
    return item.Content__c.substring(0, 255) + '...';
  }
}
```